# How to escape this ViewData in label?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I always heard the benefit of making html helpers but no one really shows how it would look if you did not right an html helper.

So I just wanted to write a label with plan html and not my html helper I made

```
<label for="<% ViewData["View_CoursePrefix"].ToString(); %>"></label>
```

I am trying to put a viewData in the "for" part but it keeps saying semi colon expected. I tried to escape the quotes but that does not work. What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the difference between `<% %>` & `<%= %>`

When you write:

```
<%= ViewData["View_CoursePrefix"] %>
```

Behind the scenes, the WebForms view engine translates it to:

```
<% Response.Write(ViewData["View_CoursePrefix"]); %>
```

So to get your version to work, you'd have to wrap it in `Response.Write()`.

HTHs,
Charles

Oh, and FYI... In ASP.NET 4.0 they're introducing `<%: %>` which will automatically HtmlEncode the output. See [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/25/html-encoding-code-nuggets.aspx) from Phil Haack

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="<%=ViewData["View_CoursePrefix"] %>">some text</label>
```

Comment: why can't you do toString()? I know the equal complies it to the string but I am just wondering the other way too.